# Unable to upload media for WP on fresh install of WP [Local - MAMP]

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, media, mamp

I am just getting started with locally developing a WP site.

I am able to add posts, create pages, add plugins and upload themes on my local version of WP. However, I am facing an issue uploading media.

Any time I upload a media file the upload fails and I get the following error "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2018/06."
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiwAy.png)

Many other users have identified that I need to update the permissions of my wp-content folder, but in my local host the permission has been set so that all users can read & write these folders.

Without the ability to upload media, i will not be able to fully develop my WP site locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Info:

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome 67.0.3396.87
WP Version: 4.9.6
Local Server tool MAMP